# Cannot get DatePicker to work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

Depending on what theme I use - My date picker will not work and it is killing me.

I have done this many times before but am getting a strange reaction: I can get it to work without my custom bootstrap theme but with it, it will not work. The page loads as how it should look but the datepicker doesnt work but if I remove my theme it will.

The reason I say this is strange is because I've used this theme on a project 2 days ago and it worked perfectly fine but now it wont on this new project.

```
@model WADTrackerApplication.Models.Weight

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Weight</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model._Weight, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model._Weight, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model._Weight, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AdditonalComments, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdditonalComments, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AdditonalComments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
    </div>

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('DateTime').datetimepicker({
                viewMode: 'years',
                format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
            });
        });

    </script>
</body>

</html>




<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: $('DateTime').datetimepicker({ ? You need to specify whther it is a class or id right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your javascript code has a wrong selector `$('DateTime')` will select all elements of type Datetime, which do not exist in your markup.

Add a descriptive class or ID to the input you want to act as a datepicker:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control date-picker" } })
```

Then use that selector in your js snippet:

```
$(function () {
  $('.date-picker').datetimepicker({
    viewMode: 'years',
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
  });
});
```

Comment: Even when I type ".datepicker()" it doesn't even start to attempt to autocomplete it

Comment: If I chose "layout = null" it then works but there is no css on the page.

Comment: What if you remove the javascript code entirely? Bootstrap and Jquery should do the rest automatically

Comment: as in the script links or the whole "$(function..."